# adding annotations while copying a pdf file to another

Tags: java, itext

I am trying to add annotations to every Page which gets copied to my new pdf but not able to do that...

Here is my code.

```
import com.lowagie.text.Document;
import com.lowagie.text.Rectangle;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;


public class Annotations {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("string-to-pdf.pdf");
            Document document = new Document(reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(1));
            PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document,
                    new FileOutputStream("temp.pdf"));
            copy.setPdfVersion(PdfWriter.VERSION_1_5);
            document.open();
            for(int i = 1; i <=reader.getNumberOfPages();i++){
                copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader,i));
                copy.addAnnotation(PdfAnnotation.createLink(copy, new Rectangle(200f, 700f, 30455454f, 800f), PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_TOGGLE, PdfAction.javaScript("app.alert('Hello');\r", copy)));
            }

            document.newPage();
            // page 3
            PdfContentByte pcb = new PdfContentByte(copy);
            pcb.setColorFill(new Color(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00));

            document.close();

        } catch (Exception de) {
            de.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

the files are getting copied but can't see the annotations in the new file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PdfCopy` is for faithful page copying, not for creation; thus, modification routines inherited from `PdfWriter` are disabled, e.g.

```
@Override
public void addAnnotation(PdfAnnotation annot) {  }
```

Dedicated manipulations are possible, though, by means of page stamps, cf. `createPageStamp`. The JavaDocs of that method contain some example usage code including an addition of an annotation:

```
PdfImportedPage page = copy.getImportedPage(reader, 1);
PdfCopy.PageStamp ps = copy.createPageStamp(page);
ps.addAnnotation(PdfAnnotation.createText(copy, new Rectangle(50, 180, 70, 200), "Hello", "No Thanks", true, "Comment"));
PdfContentByte under = ps.getUnderContent();
under.addImage(img);
PdfContentByte over = ps.getOverContent();
over.beginText();
over.setFontAndSize(bf, 18);
over.setTextMatrix(30, 30);
over.showText("total page " + totalPage);
over.endText();
ps.alterContents();
copy.addPage(page);
```

Beware, though, applying a `PageStamp` like this actually manipulates the original `PdfReader`. Afterwards, therefore, don't continue using the `PdfReader` instance assuming its contents are the original contents, in particular the pagestamped copied pages are dirty.

Comment: no no no you have taken the question really very wrong... I want to add so many annotations on a single page

Comment: *"no no no you have taken the question really very wrong"* - then explain. The code example clearly shows how to (among other things) add an annotation to a page to copy, and that's what you want to do, don't you?