# How to add content in existing PDF page using PdfWriter and PdfCopy in one loop

Tags: java, itext

I have to use two methods to write content in existing PDF page using PdfWriter and to merge PDFs using PdfCopy. I want to do it in one loop.

PdfWriter object is not merging PDF like source page. We have to create a new page (A4) and add content into it from source page. To avoid that, we can use Pdfcopy object which merges exact size of PDF pages as source file has. The problem here is I have to merge first and then call the merged file to add content again. Since the PDF file has lot of pages, it's taking lot of time to perform this operation using two loops.

I can't use PdfCopy option in same loop.

Here aremy two methods:

```
public boolean mergePDFsinOneFile(List<InputStream> list, OutputStream outputStream,List<Integer> allDocId,int conDocId){

    com.itextpdf.text.Document document = new com.itextpdf.text.Document();
    PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, outputStream);

    document.open();
    
    String storagePath = sql.getDirectoryPath();
    PdfReader reader = null;
    
    for(int docId : allDocId) {
        String finalPath = "";
        ResultSet doc = sql.getDocumentDetails(docId);
        if(doc.next()) {
            String relative_path = doc.getString("RELATIVE_PATH"); 
            
            if(relative_path.endsWith(".pdf") || relative_path.endsWith(".PDF")){
                
                finalPath = storagePath +relative_path;
                reader = new PdfReader(finalPath);
                
                copy.addDocument(reader);
                copy.freeReader(reader);
            }
        }
    }
    
    reader.close();
    outputStream.flush();
    document.close();
    outputStream.close();
    
    System.out.println("document merged");
    return true;
    
}
```

And another method is:

```
public boolean mergePDFsinOneFileTe(List<InputStream> list, OutputStream outputStream,List<Integer> allDocId,int conDocId){

    com.itextpdf.text.Document document = new com.itextpdf.text.Document();//PageSize.A4
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);
    document.open();
    
    PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont();
    cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 8);
    
    String storagePath = sql.getDirectoryPath();
    ResultSet conDocResult = sql.getDocumentDetails(conDocId);
    String printText = "";
    String docName = "";
    if(conDocResult.next())
        docName = conDocResult.getString("DOCUMENT_NAME");
    
    for(int docId : allDocId) {
        String finalPath = "";
        printText = "";
        ResultSet doc = sql.getDocumentDetails(docId);
        if(doc.next()) {
            String relative_path = doc.getString("RELATIVE_PATH"); 
            
            if(relative_path.endsWith(".pdf") || relative_path.endsWith(".PDF")){
                String docTypePrefix = "";
                int typeValue = 0;
                
                finalPath = storagePath +relative_path;
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(finalPath);
                System.out.println("finalPath "+finalPath);
                
                ResultSet docTypeResult = sql.getDoctypeDetails(doc.getInt("DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID"));
                if(docTypeResult.next())
                    docTypePrefix = docTypeResult.getString("CONSO_SUFFIX_NAME"); //PREFIX
                
                ResultSet consolValue = sql.getConsolidateTypeValueByTypeId(doc.getInt("DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID"));
                if(consolValue.next())
                    typeValue = Integer.parseInt(consolValue.getString("VALUE"));
                
                printText = docName + "-" + "[" + typeValue + "]" + "-" + docTypePrefix;
                for(int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages();i++){
                    PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
                    cb.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
                    cb.beginText();
                    ColumnText.showTextAligned(cb, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase(printText), document.left(), document.bottom() - 20, 0);
                    cb.endText();
                    document.newPage();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    outputStream.flush();
    document.close();
    outputStream.close();
    System.out.println("document merged");
    return true;
    
}
```

How to write content while looping and merge at same time?

Comment: First of all, what you do in your second method should be done using a `PdfStamper` instead of a `PdfWriter`. And in a single pass you can do that using a `PdfCopy` with `PageStamp` use.

Comment: I tried with PdfStamper also. But we have to define output path for each file while merging when we write using PdfStamper. So can't mention PdfStamper at the time of merging.

Comment: No PdfStamper but a `PageStamp`! See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60318520/1729265)

Comment: @mkl thanks for sharing the link. let me try it out.